# How do I implement such layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking for this widget name so I can look for existing implementations. I saw it in app written with **PhoneGap**. The behaviour: you click on the view part and then it slides and shows itself.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably talking about the SlidingDrawer widget. Not sure if that is what you want.
Anyway you can check the doc here [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Here an [example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely want to use a `SlidingDrawer`.  I have implemented this exact type of layout using a view extending `SlidingDrawer` for further customizations.

What you need to do is add a `SlidingDrawer` to perhaps a `FrameLayout`.  This `FrameLayout` should have a static height(say `200dp`) for the `SlidingDrawer` to live in.  Place the `FrameLayout` at the bottom of the layout using perhaps a `RelativeLayout`.

You may find that the `SlidingDrawer` behaves not to your expectations in some cases(adding more complex objects which respond to user interactions to the `handle` of the `SlidingDrawer` can produce problems)